# VBA insert row if I+2 contains certain text

Tags: excel, vba

So I have an excel sheet that can have anywhere from 5-1500 lines. Most lines have: 1) Title Row, 2) patient information, 3) blank row. Then it repeats. Some lines have 1) Title Row, 2) patient info, 3) additional patient info, 4)blank row. I need to insert a line between Rows 2&3 if there is info in row 3. Does this make sense?
Example:
--------A---------------------b-----------------c-------------------d--------
1-----acct #--------patient name------dr name------ date of service
2------123456-------Mickey Mouse-----Donald Duck--------1/4/19
3----------((((((((((((((all of this row is blank)))))))))))))))))))))----------

Or it could be this:
--------A---------------------b--------------------c-------------------d------
1-----acct #--------patient name--------dr name------ date of service
2------123456-------Mickey Mouse-----Donald Duck--------1/4/19
3------123456-------Mickey Mouse-----Donald Duck--------1/4/19
4----------((((((((((((((all of this row is blank)))))))))))))))))))))----------

Then this same format repeats throughout the sheet with different info of course. What I need is if row 3 has any info then insert a row between tows 2 & 3, but if row 3 is blank then skip to the next set.

This is the code I have so far but it is adding rows every other row no matter what.

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
Dim I As Long
For I = 6 To lastRow
If Cells(I + 2, 9).Text <> "" Then
Rows(I + 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
lastRow=lastRow+1

End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: (If you're going to be inserting/removing rows, instead I suggest starting at the end and working your way up.)

Comment: unfortunately, I am completely new to VBA and have no idea how to even attempt this.

Comment: So every time there is a blank row, insert another one?

Comment: No only if row 3 has data in it, if row 3 is blank then leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

As @BruceWayne stated in the comments, When inserting or deleting rows, columns or cells, it's helpful to iterate backwards. The `Step` parameter of a `For-Next` loop allows you to define how you would like to iterate. It defaults to `Step 1`. So instead of iterating from `I = 6 to lastRow` try

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
For i = lastRow To 6 Step -1
    If Cells(i - 1, 9).Text <> "" And Cells(i, 9).Text <> "" Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
Next i
```

This would insert a row at your current iteration if both the current cell and the cell above it had data in them.

It's worth noting that if you were to iterate to row 1, the `If` statement above would raise an error, but you'd never need to.

**EDIT:**

If what you need is to only add a row between patient info and additional patient info, you'd need to find a consistently identifiable piece of data to add as a condition to the `If` statement.

Comment: I tried this but it adds a blank row every other row. I only need it if row 3 (of the block) has data.

Comment: I edited my answer, but you'll need to include something consistently identifiable in your `If` statement. Perhaps something that you can identify as `additional patient info`.

Comment: there is a column that will always have one of two strings in it "POS1" or "POS2"

Comment: You'll have to be specific with which column.

Comment: Column J will always have either POS1 or POS2 (except for the blank rows that already exist)

Comment: Always or only when the row isn't blank/a header? If the latter is the case, just add an additional condition to your `If` statement `And Cells(i - 1, 10).Text Like "POS*"`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

Customize the variables to fit your needs

```
Sub InsertRows()

    ' Define object variables
    Dim rangeEval As Range
    Dim currentCell As Range

    ' Define other variables
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rowCounter As Integer

    ' >>>> Customize this
    sheetName = "Sheet1"

    ' Initialize the used range in column A ' Change the number in .Columns(1) to use another column
    Set rangeEval = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName).UsedRange.Columns(1)


    ' Loop through each cell in range
    For Each currentCell In rangeEval.Cells

        ' We use this counter to check if we are every third row
        rowCounter = rowCounter + 1

        ' If this is the third row and there is something in the cell, insert one row
        If rowCounter Mod 3 = 0 And currentCell.Value <> vbNullString Then

            currentCell.EntireRow.Insert

        ' Reset the counter if there is nothing in the cell
        ElseIf currentCell.Value = vbNullString Then

            rowCounter = 0

        End If

    Next currentCell


End Sub
```